# What causes error in powershell when adding process to arrayList?

Tags: powershell, arraylist

My code

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Global:shells=@()
$cmdProc = Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit", ("-command grunt "+ [string]$argList) -WorkingDirectory $fwd -PassThru
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Global:shells.Add(($cmdProc))
```

does add a PowerShell process to `$shells` arrayList. But it also displays an error message:

```
cannot convert the "0" value of type "System.Int32" to type
"System.Collections.ArrayList".
At line:16 char:1
+ [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Global:shells.Add(($cmdProc))
```

It is definitely related to index of arrayList it adds at, but what's going on? I can access `$shells[0]` just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last statement:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Global:shells.Add(($cmdProc))
```

PowerShell attempts to cast the output from the `Add()` method call (which is `0`, the index you just inserted at), to an ArrayList because of the `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` literal in front.

Change it to:

```
[void]$Global:shells.Add(($cmdProc))
```

Answer (score 1):

In my mind, the better solution would be to set the type of your array properly, i.e.:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process[]] $Global:shells = @();

try {
    $shells += Start-Process powershell <blah blah> -PassThru;
    } #try
catch [System.Exception] {
    # blah
    } #catch
```

...for those not familiar with PowerShell, the **-passthru** parameter causes the **Start-Process** cmdlet to return the object that it generated.  This is normally done so that you can use this object to push further down the powershell "pipeline".  In the case of **Start-Process**, it returns objects of type **System.Diagnostics.Process**, thus the static data type assignment.

Comment: Would be fine if `[System.Diagnostics.Process[]]` was not a static collection. I generally try to avoid the `+=` for static arrays where I need to add staff. It actually seems somewhat unfortunate to me that powershell basic array types do not support `Add()`, `Remove()` etc. methods natively...